# What's the purpose of a leading colon in a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've starting using the Wijmo toolkit, and came across quite a few example selectors similar to this in their documentation pages:

```
$(":input[type='radio']").wijradio();
```

I'd have written mine like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').wijradio();
```

Do these do the same or is there something I'm missing?

Note that there are two differences above: the first selector is prefixed with a colon and has quotes for the input type.

Comment: One is the specialized [**`:input`**](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) selector, while the other is a generic [**`Element`**](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) selector.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`:input` is a [jQuery extension](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) while `input` is a CSS selector.

`textarea`, `button`, and `select` elements would be matched by the former, but not the latter.

The latter is faster, so use it for your specific `radio` example. Use `:input` when you want "all form elements" even if they aren't strictly `<input>` tags. Even in that case, the recommendation is to use a standard CSS selector first, then use `.filter(':input')` on that set.

> Because :input is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :input cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using :input to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then
>   use .filter(":input").

In the 1.7.2 source, the :input filter tests a regular expression against the nodeName:

```
input: function( elem ) {
            return (/input|select|textarea|button/i).test( elem.nodeName );
},
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! And the type-quotes are completely optional?

Comment: Honestly, I've never used `[type=]` with `:input` because if I'm looking for a specific type, using `:input` to get all of them first seems the long way around. For pure CSS selectors, my understanding is that quotes are standard, but browsers are forgiving. You can quickly test it with/without here http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors/demo

Comment: so $(":checked") gives checked boxes .. is this also jquery extension?

Comment: @David Ruttka: "browsers are forgiving" only applies to HTML, and to CSS in quirks mode. That statement doesn't apply to CSS in standards mode. Quotes can legally be omitted in some cases.

Comment: can we have an example of `first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":input").` ?

Comment: Is there a list of these jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 17):

the `$("input")` selector will choose only elements of the type input

while the `$(":input")` selector will catch all the inputs elements (such as textarea, select, input etc...)

for further information, go the jQuery official documentation about the `:input` selector at:

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Answer (score 6):

The `:input` selector basically selects all `form` controls(input, textarea, select and button elements) where as `input` selector selects all the elements by tag name `input`.

Since radio button is a `form` element and also it uses `input` tag so they both can be used to select radio button. However both approaches differ the way they find the elements and thus each have different performance benefits.